# configuring 2 digium card in single system?

Tags: asterisk, telecommunication

I have two digium cards ,models are TE420 4 port card,TE121 single port card.

After the configuration 4 port card

if i execute "dahdi show status" in asterisk prompt , I got following output

```
Description                              Alarms  IRQ    bpviol CRC4 
T4XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 1                OK      46      0      0    
T4XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 2                OK      46      0      0    
T4XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 3                OK      46      0      0    
T4XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 4                OK      46      0      0    
Wildcard TE121 card 0                    OK      32457   0      0
```

Why I am not getting the Span 5 for the single port card.

Comment: can you share your, /etc/dahdi/system.conf and /etc/asterisk/chan_dahdi.conf

Answer (score 0):

check by typing pri show spans in asterisk cli
and also in linux shell type dahdi_cfg -vvvv  it will output all the channesl configured

Answer (score 0):

The description you see there is the span description filled in by the DAHDI drivers for each span. When they fill in the description they do not yet know what global span number they were assigned. The 1-4 is just showing the spans that are exported by card 0. Since TE121 only export a single span, they only indicate their card number.

If you're using these cards with PRI, I agree that with striker that 'pri show spans' is a more useful command to see the status of the spans.

Running dahdi_maint from the console is also a good way to see the current status of any DAHDI spans you have configured in your system.